# Save status of AVD in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I was wondering if there was a way to save the Android emulator status in Android Studio, to open it without waiting the boot time every time.

I've looked around but it seems it's not possible, or at least I didn't find anything.

Thanks in advance!